# Mailchimp integration in my own html registration form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I am having a sign up form which is a raw HTML with stripe integration, Now i want to integrate a mail chimp into it.I have placed a code

```
<p>
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mc4wp-subscribe" value="1" />
Subscribe to our newsletter.    </label>
</p>
```

in my html page. I am not getting the subscribers list in the admin pannel.

Answer (score 0):

login to your MailChimp account then manage contacts-> group then create there a group with checkbox after then go to signup forms and embed code will show the check box edit the code under then forms tag like below

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
 /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//dada.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=804ce11ffe4a5684c85f88d38&amp;id=d5ab97dfc9" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[4917][1]" id="mce-group[4917]-4917-0"><label for="mce-group[4917]-4917-0">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
</div>
 <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
 </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_804ce11ffe4a5684c85f88d38_d5ab97dfc9" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: ya thatsfine, but i dont need a extra form to do this i need to integrate the mailchimp form to my current registration form which i have given in my code area.

Comment: See here also also we are having a form with the button , I already have a form with submit button it will do some action, i want to integrate the mail chimp within that form(in submit button),Is there any hook for updating the mail chimp subscribers list.